# updating a variable local to a function when said variable is passed to another function as an argument

Tags: javascript

As stated in the question, I am trying to find a way that would allow me to update a local variable to a function within another function, if said variable is given as an argument. In the project that I am creating there will be multiple instances of "foo"(referencing the code below), certain contents will be updated based on the foo instance's counter that I would like to be updated within the update function.

```
 function foo(){
         this.counter = 0;
    }

    function update(fooInstance){
      fooInstance.counter+=1;
    }

    x = new foo()

    setInterval(function({
      update(x)
    }),1000)
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? (apart from the typo)

Comment: You can't update a *variable*, because JS function arguments are passed by value, but if you pass a reference to an *object* you can modify that object. And the code you've shown should do so without any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
setInterval(function({
  update(x)
}),1000)
```

to

```
setInterval(function(){
  update(x)
},1000)
```